# Is there a more elegant way to write these conditions?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
    if(first - second >=2 || first - second <=-2 || first - third >=2 || first - third <=-2 || second - third >=2 || second - third <=-2)
```

It's disgusting.

I have three values that have to be checked, and if any two of them have a >= 2 difference, then I run through some tasks.

I'm curious, can you suggest a way that would make this more pleasant? Thanks

Comment: Hint: [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

Comment: use `Math.abs` and you can halve the number of queries

Comment: more elegant to a human or a machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( Math.max(first, second, third) - Math.min(first, second, third) >= 2 )
```

or a bit less efficient:

```
var a = [first, second, third].sort((a, b) => a - b));
if ( a[2] - a[0] >= 2 )
```

Comment: A few good solutions in this post but I think this is as elegant as it's going to get :) Thanks Slai

Answer (score 3):

Throw the subtraction expressions in an array and use Array#some() and Math.abs

```
if ( [first - second, first - third , second - third].some(n => Math.abs(n) >=2 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can breakdown theif statement to 3 conditions simply bt using `Math.abs()`.
Here's is it :

```
if( Math.abs( first - second ) >= 2 || Math.abs( first - third ) >= 2 || Math.abs( second - third ) >= 2 )
```

Math.abs() function returns the absolute value of it's argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to approach the problem if you were willing to use a function to determine the maximum difference between an array of numbers. The shortest if probably the neatest, just a few ideas on how you may approach the problem:

```js
const shortGetMaxDifference = numbers => Math.max(...numbers) - Math.min(...numbers);

const getMaxDifference = numbers => {
  const sorted = numbers
    .sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1)
    
  return sorted[0] - sorted[sorted.length-1]
}

const longWindedGetMaxDifference = numbers => numbers
  .map(i => numbers.map(j => Math.max(i, j) - Math.min(i, j))
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr], [])
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1)[0]
  
const numbers = [1, 4, -5, 7, 13]

console.log(shortGetMaxDifference(numbers))
console.log(getMaxDifference(numbers))
console.log(longWindedGetMaxDifference(numbers))

const first = 1;
const second = 3;
const third = 2;

if (getMaxDifference([first, second, third]) >= 2) {
  console.log('The difference is bigger');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.abs() will help you, you can break the several conditions to only 3 conditions.

`Math.abs(first - second) >= 2` and similarly others

Answer (score 0):

One (objectively) more elegant way is to utilize the [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) function:

```
if (Math.abs(first-second) >= 2 || Math.abs(first-third) >= 2 || Math.abs(second-third) >= 2)){
    // do something
}
```

A subjective *(and completely unnecessary I might add)* way to make it aesthetically more pleasing would be:

```
function plusminus2(val1, val2){
   return ((Math.abs(val1 - val2) >= 2) ? true : false);
}

if (plusminus2(first, second) || plusminus2(first, third) || plusminus2(second, third)){
  // do something
}
```

But I generally would not recommend doing something like this. While it may save you a couple of seconds writing some `if` statements *(presuming there's more than this single one)* it's going to cause an absolute headache anyone else trying to comprehend your code or even yourself if you open it 4 years down the line!

Comment: The only thing that creates a headache here is the `condition ? true : false` thing.